# simple math question from civil service exam

Tags: problem-solving

The weight per foot of a length of square bar 4" x 4" in cross section as compared with one 2" x 2" in cross section, is **______** as much.

A. Twice
B. 2 1/2 times
C. 3 times
D. 4 times

This question exactly as writtin appears in NY states civil service exam. The answer key says the correct answer is C.

Someone over at the test writing center is smoking some good stuff.

This is one of several incorrect answers and oddish question.

Can someone please give the correct answer as I am arguing with another gentleman about it

Comment: Four times as much

Comment: The answer should be $D$, and per foot has nothing to do with the answer.

Comment: Andre you must be smoking the same stuff...

Comment: Yes, it is interfering with my eyesight, the answer is $4$, which I thought had label C.

Comment: So the guy who still doesnt believe me here insists the answer is "A" and i cant figure out how else to explain it. He says im wrong. He says we are all wrong.. can someone please explain it im out of ideas.

Comment: I even drew him a diagram and he still doesnt get it.. maybe im not explaining correctly so if someone cares to give it go...

Comment: Yay hes convinced now.. it only took 5 people.. ty all

Comment: What is a civil service and do they pay well?

Comment: Maybe the 2 by 2 bar is made of heavier material  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $4''\times 4''$ square bar has four times the cross-sectional area as the $2''\times 2''$ bar.  (Draw the cross-sections to see this.) If the bars are of the same length and (uniform) mass density, then the weight of the $4''\times 4''$ bar is four times the weight of the $2''\times 2''$ bar.

If your friend still doesn't see the point after showing him a drawing, then ask him to put *four* of the $2''\times 2''$ bars together to form one similar in size and shape to the $4''\times 4''$ bar.

Answer (score 1):

Mass is proportional to volume *. If we ignore density and take each bar to be $l$ inches long, the first bar has volume $4"\cdot\,4"\cdot\,l=16l$ & the volume of the second bar is $2"\cdot\,2"\cdot\,l=4l$. Clearly $16l=4\cdot4l$ so the volume (& thus, mass) is $4$ times greater.

*$m=\rho V$